# Can't show Widget on ListView.Builder when Widget is obtained by function on Flutter

Tags: listview, dart, flutter, widget

I'm trying populate a `ListView` with `switch`, so I want use a function per widget needed, avoiding write a lot of code on `case:` option. My problem is that when I uses a function to return the widget, nothing is showed on screen, but if I write all code of widget on `case` option, the content of screen is showed. To show my problem, I'm using just the first option.

**Code (showing nothing):**

```
  Widget getBody(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: new ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 9,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            switch (index) {
              case 0: // Descricao
                showDescription();
                break;
              case 1: // Produto
                _showProduto();
                break;
              case 2: // Preco Unitario
                _showPrecoUnitario();
                break;
              case 3: // Quantidade
                _showQtd();
                break;
              case 4: // Total
                _showTotal();
                break;
              case 5: // Pago por
                _showPagoPor();
                break;
              case 6: // Conta de referencia
                _showContaDeReferencia();
                break;
              case 7: // Data
                _showData();
                break;
              case 8: // Notas
                _showNotas();
                break;
              default:
                print('DEFAUL ITEM BUILDER');
            }
          }),
    );
  }

 Widget showDescription() {
    return new TextField(
        cursorColor: Color(0xFF801E48),
        controller: _txtDescricao,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            fillColor: Color(0xFF801E48),
            labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, color: Color(0xFF801E48)),
            hintText: 'Ex.: Almoço com cliente',
            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Color(0xFF801E48),
            )),
            labelText: 'Descrição'));
  }
```

**Code working:**

```
  Widget getBody(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: new ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 9,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            switch (index) {
              case 0: // Descricao
                return new TextField(
                    cursorColor: Color(0xFF801E48),
                    controller: _txtDescricao,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        fillColor: Color(0xFF801E48),
                        labelStyle:
                            TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, color: Color(0xFF801E48)),
                        hintText: 'Ex.: Almoço com cliente',
                        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                          color: Color(0xFF801E48),
                        )),
                        labelText: 'Descrição'));
                break;
              case 1: // Produto
                _showProduto();
                break;
              case 2: // Preco Unitario
                _showPrecoUnitario();
                break;
              case 3: // Quantidade
                _showQtd();
                break;
              case 4: // Total
                _showTotal();
                break;
              case 5: // Pago por
                _showPagoPor();
                break;
              case 6: // Conta de referencia
                _showContaDeReferencia();
                break;
              case 7: // Data
                _showData();
                break;
              case 8: // Notas
                _showNotas();
                break;
              default:
                print('DEFAUL ITEM BUILDER');
            }
          }),
    );
  }
```

I don't see no one reason to ins't work, but on the screen nothing is showed, I'm very confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the return `keyword` , like this :

```
            case 0: // Descricao
               return showDescription();
```